# Appending JSON array with values from the array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I have a json array with the following structure

```
{
        "connection": {
            "established": "yes"
        },
        "ping": {
            "server": "thirteen"
        }
    }
```

also i have a simple array of server names called `servers`

my goal is to append the values from the `servers` array to the `Json`array - copying the *"connection", "established", "yes", "ping", "server"* values and just modifying the *"thirteen"* value.

So that the end result would look something like this

```
{
        "connection": {
            "established": "yes"
        },
        "ping": {
            "server": "fourteen"
        }
    }, 
{
        "connection": {
            "established": "yes"
        },
        "ping": {
            "server": "fifteen"
        }
    }
```

e.t.c.

I tried implementing the `SwiftyJSON` array library, but didn't really understand how to append values to the json itself.

Is there a way to manage it?

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: What you have tried? show your code.

Comment: I just added the swift library file, I've seen some examples of for loops on swiftly github, but no more than that

Comment: That's not an array, it's a dictionary. JSON arrays are represented with square brackets `[]`

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. Thank you for clarification. How should I proceed with value appending? @vadian

Comment: to process the dictionaries in Swift create an `Array`, convert the JSON string to dictionary with `SwiftyJSON`, and append the dictionary to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for. It took me some time to understand what you are asking for :)

```
// Initial Data - So called JSON Array
var dict1 = ["connection" : ["established": "yes"], "ping" : ["server" : "twelve"]]
var dict2 = ["connection" : ["established": "yes"], "ping" : ["server" : "thirteen"]]
var array = [dict1, dict2]

// Servers Array
var servers = ["fourteen", "fifteen"]

// First lets filter out dictionary where ping.server = thirteen
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ping.server = %@", "thirteen")

// Filtered dictionary
var targetDict = array.filter({
    predicate.evaluateWithObject($0)
})[0]

// Now lets loop on servers and modify filtered dictionary and add to parent array
for server in servers {
    targetDict["ping"]!["server"]! = server
    array.append(targetDict)
}

print("\(array)")
```

Comment: works as a charm! thank you ! sorry for not being clear enough

Comment: No worries... Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try this using SwiftyJSON (Not tested)

```
Json["ping"] as NSDictionary)["server"] as NSString = "Your Value"
```

Comment: not sure how it's supposed to work... once i insert the code, i'm getting "Expecting expression for size of array type" error. And what about the ")" symbol, should it be there?